# Cast list of interface to list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a method that returns `List<ThisInterface>`. I would expect that I would be able to cast the results of that method to `List<ThisClass>`, as long as ThisClass implements ThisInterface. However, I receive the following error trying to do so:

> Unable to cast object of type `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[IThisInterface]` to type `System.Collections.Generic.List’1[ThisClass]`.

Any thoughts? Do I need to write a constructor for this?

Comment: Where is the code where you are casting?

Comment: Why are you casting? You should be able to access the methods on the interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `List<IThisInterface>`, then you cannot cast that list object to `List<ThisClass>`. Even if all the items inside of the list are `ThisClass` objects, the list is still a list of `IThisInterface` objects.

What you need to do is create a new `List<ThisClass>` list and then populate that with all the items of the original list but cast *those* to `ThisClass` first.

Fortunately, that is exactly what the LINQ method [`Enumerable.Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb341406.aspx) does:

```
List<IThisInterface> list = GetData();

// cast the list to a `ThisClass` list
List<ThisClass> newList = list.Cast<ThisClass>().ToList();
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: I just tested this solution out and it worked like a charm. Many thanks to you, @poke.

Comment: @christok Worth mentioning that this will throw an exception if any of the items are not `ThisClass`, instead you could use `list.OfType<ThisClass>().ToList()`. Of course, this also begs the question of *why* you want to cast them in the first place? There's a reason you have the interfaces...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your expectation is incorrect.  A `List<IThisInterface>` is allowed to contain elements of *any type that implements `IThisInterface`*.  If you were allowed to cast this to `List<ThisClass>`, the cast would add a restriction - suddenly only a specific implementation of the interface would be allowed in the list, and for example when you get an item from the list you would be allowed to assume it is of type `ThisClass` - which it may or may not be since what you were given was a less restrictive list.

Comment: This totally makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

No (by way of example)

```
IAnimal animal = new Giraffe(); // Giraffe is an IAnimal so OK.
Lion lion = (Lion)animal; // should this work? Lion is an IAnimal???
```

Update:

For some it must be stated that Giraffe and Lion both implement an interface called IAnimal and that Giraffe is not a subclass of Lion. Others managed to understand that IThisInterface is akin to IAnimal and ThisClass is akin to Lion with a rhetorical "should this work".

The answer is self evidently no. A Lion is a concretion of IAnimal, but it does not follow that having an instance of IAnimal means that you have a Lion. Such a cast will throw but is also obviously wrong and so neatly illustrates the problem. In the same way, ThisClass implementing IThisInterface means that ThisClass is a concretion of IThisInterface, but just because you find yourself in possession of a collection of IThisInterface's, does not mean that you can assume that such is a list of ThisClass's. It might be, but equally it might be any other object that implements IThisInterface.

Anyway, if you search for covariance and contravariance you will find a number of similar questions that will let you understand further.

Comment: This answer is missing a few things for it to be instructive, such as a definition for `IAnimal`, `Giraffe`, and `Lion`. Also, it's missing a variable name in the `Lion` assignment. And it doesn't mention which exception is thrown (or even if one ***is*** thrown), nor does it say *why* this doesn't work.